# Implementing erase in a dynamic array for string type crashes

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memcpy

I am trying to implementing stl vector in C++ for types like string,int, ulong etc using template class. The erase function found below is working fine for all other data types except string.

```
template <typename T>
void myArr<T>::erase(ULONG index)
{
    if(index >= count)
        return;
    T* temp_arr = new T[max_count];
    if(index == 0)
    {
        memcpy(temp_arr,(arr+1),(count-1)*sizeof(T));
    }
    else if(index == count-1)
    {
        memcpy(temp_arr,arr,(count-1)*sizeof(T));
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(temp_arr,arr,(index-1)*sizeof(T));
        memcpy(temp_arr+index,arr+index+1,(count-index)*sizeof(T));
    }
    delete[] arr;
    arr = temp_arr;
    count--;
}
```

When string is the array type, the program crashes with memory access violation 0x0005. How to handle this for strings data type..?

Comment: is it supposed to be a null terminated string?

Comment: "_is working fine for all other data types except string._" Do you mean `std::string`? If so, `memcpy` doesn't invoke copy-constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `memcpy` on non trivially copyable types.  `std::string` is not trvially copyable so you can't use it on it.

What you need to do is have erase call special versions of erase depending on the type the container holds.  If it is a trivial type, then call the version of `erase` that uses `memcpy`.  If it is not then call the version of `erase` that uses a for loop and does a naive copy/move operation.

Comment: How can i have a different function for non trivial data type alone - as i have implemented template?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `memcpy()` for non-trivial types, like `std::string`, that may need to copy internal data from one instance to another.  In this case, you need to copy each element individually using its own `operator=`, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void myArr<T>::erase(ULONG index)
{
    if (index >= count)
        return;

    T* temp_arr = new T[max_count];

    // copy elements before the index...
    for(int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
        temp_arr[i] = arr[i];
    }

    // copy elements after the index...
    for (int i = index + 1; i < count; ++i) {
        temp_arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
    }

    delete[] arr;
    arr = temp_arr;

    --count;
}
```

Or better, you can use [`std::copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) instead, which is optimized for copying trivial types, and "does the right thing" for copying non-trivial types:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void myArr<T>::erase(ULONG index)
{
    if (index >= count)
        return;

    T* temp_arr = new T[max_count];

    // copy elements before the index...
    std::copy(arr, arr + index, temp_arr);

    // copy elements after the index...
    std::copy(arr + (index+1), arr + count, temp_arr + index);

    delete[] arr;
    arr = temp_arr;

    --count;
}
```

Alternatively, since your class seems to have a concept of the array having a capacity vs a count, you don't actually need to allocate a new array at all, you can simply modify the existing array inline so as to shrink its count without affecting its capacity (this is basically what `std::vector::erase()` does):

```cpp
template <typename T>
void myArr<T>::erase(ULONG index)
{
    if (index >= count)
        return;

    // shift elements after the index down one slot...
    std::copy(arr + (index+1), arr + count, arr + index);

    // clear the now-unused last slot of its data...
    arr[count-1] = T();

    --count;
}
```

Comment: how can i find if it is trivial or non trivial, when i use a template? I mean for string alone how can i define a different function??

Comment: when using copy i get this error - Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators' - Tried defining secure no warnings , but still same error..

Comment: @Sel_va see [`std::is_trivial`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) and related traits. And do what the compiler says - read the documentation about [Checked Iterators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/checked-iterators?view=vs-2019). Since your code uses raw pointers, they are considered to be unchecked iterators. So either 1) don't use standard algorithms (not recommended), or 2) use the [`checked_array_iterator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/checked-array-iterator-class?view=vs-2019) adapter.